# How to generate exe file form already existing exe file with extra run parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, exe

I have test.exe, I would like to generate new anothertest.exe file which will contain test.exe and run it like test.exe -param1. It is important to use .NET Core

Comment: Why not simply write a batch-script that calls your app with the param set?

Comment: You could embed `test.exe` as an embedded resource and use [Process.start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-2.1) to execute it with run parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to create another app for this target.
Simple bat-file would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You could embed `test.exe` as an embedded resource and use [Process.start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-2.1) to execute it with run parameters.